# Stop Download Image automatically when browsed via URL show image into browser

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.get('/get/image/*', (req, res) => {
    const path = req.params[0];
    const fName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'image/png');
    res.download(uploadBasePath + path, fName);
})
```

This is downloading the images instead of displaying them over the browser. I want to display on the browser not do auto download. How can I fix it?

Comment: try doing `res.send(<img>Path</img>)`

Comment: only string is displaying by doing so not showing image

Comment: Is your path referenced correctly? it should be calling back your server to get the image that is served via `express.static`

So if you're on local development, it will be something like <img>http://localhost:3000/yourImage</img>

Answer (score 1):

You can read the image buffer and then respond the buffer to the client with the content type is `image/jpeg`.

```
const fs = require('fs');
...
app.get('/get/image/*', (req, res) => {
  const path = req.params[0];
  const fName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  fs.readFile(uploadBasePath + fName, (err, buffer) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    res.contentType('image/jpeg');
    res.send(buffer)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but if you just want to display the image in the browser, there are several ways to do it, here is one example:

```
    // Send image url in response
    app.get('/get/image/*', (req, res) => {
        const imgUrl = 'yourimgurlhere';
        res.send({ imageUrl: imgUrl })
    })
```

And in your frontend code you refer to that url.

Example using ejs:

```
<img src="/<%= imageUrl %>" alt="My image is now displayed in the browser">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple just send the file from response in express.

```
const path = require('path')
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public",'filepath.jpg'));
```